# JavaScript Spread Operator while making a shallow copy of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, shallow-copy

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
let arr2 = [...arr]
let [...arr3] = arr
```

The arr2 and arr3, both make a shallow copy of arr. What is actually the difference?

Comment: No difference, except that `let arr2 = [...arr]` is more understandable (and thus much more common)

Comment: As @CertainPerformance said, no difference in your example. However, when doing it as in arr3,  you can [destructure the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)